# Загрузка и поворот картинок (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать поворот картинок для следующего 
[примера](https://jsfiddle.net/r1fvy3c7/6/) ?

```
 $("#fileUpload").on('change', function () {

 //Get count of selected files
 var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;

 var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
 var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
 var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
 image_holder.empty();

 if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
     if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {

         //loop for each file selected for uploaded.
         for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {

             var reader = new FileReader();
             reader.onload = function (e) {
                 $("<img />", {
                     "src": e.target.result,
                         "class": "thumb-image"
                 }).appendTo(image_holder);
             }

             image_holder.show();
             reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
         }

     } else {
         alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
     }
 } else {
     alert("Pls select only images");
 }  });
```

Приведите пожалуйста пример.

PS
Загружать необходимо в Azure blob storage, а где поворачивать по факту не важно, но на клиенте должно быть видно в превью.

Comment: уточните вопрос. куда загружать и где поворачивать: на сервере или в браузере?

Comment: Загружать в Azure blob storage, а где поворачивать по факту не важно, но на клиенте должно быть видно в превью.

Comment: добавьте это в текст вопроса, иначе его отметят как неконкретный.